# How to capture only visible image using AVCapture iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I am using AVCapture to capture the images from camera.Everything works fine except this issue.

I need the final captured image as same like which is visible in camera.But the image shows more area(which is not like visible in camera).How can i get the same visible image as final stillImageOutput?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: By more area you mean "black borders around the image" or actual visual content that is not shown during capture?

Comment: I mean actual visual content not showing.

Answer (score 0):

use your view/imageview object name instead of contentScrollview. This will help you to render the view and provide you an image.
for reference:https://charangiri.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/how-to-render-screen-taking-screen-shot-programmatically/

```
- (UIImage *) createScreenshotOfCompleteScreen
{
UIImage* image = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentScrollview.contentSize);
{
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = contentScrollview.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = contentScrollview.frame;
    contentScrollview.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    contentScrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentScrollview.contentSize.width, contentScrollview.contentSize.height);
    if ([[NSString versionofiOS] intValue]>=7)
    {
        [contentScrollview drawViewHierarchyInRect:contentScrollview.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [contentScrollview.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    contentScrollview.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    contentScrollview.frame = savedFrame;
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But i dont want to redraw the image once again.I need to get the image direct from camera.

Comment: I found out the issue.The problem is AVCapture used Preview layer as Video layer.You can see the difference while switching from Photo mode to Video capture mode on iPhone native camera app.